# Detect/check character sequence in NSView (NSResponder)

Tags: cocoa, nsstring, nsview, nsresponder

**Requirement**
I'd like to detect not a single but a sequence of characters to trigger an action, e.g when the user types '*cat*' into a `NSView` subclass - but not for a '*c*'.

Is there anything smarter other than maintaining something like a `NSMutableArray` with the last 3 characters entered in my `keyDown:` method, assembling strings from that array (via `NSData`?) and checking that string?

Sounds a bit awkward..but I can't figure an easier way (or built in functionality in `NSResponder`/`NSView`)

Comment: how you typing in NSView? is there any nstextfield etc?

Answer (score 1):

I’d just keep an NSString of the last ’n’ characters. Append to the end in keyDown:, snip from the beginning when you want (when it grows larger than ’n’), check the string to see if it contains ‘cat’ every time you get new keys.

If you’re checking less than, like, a THOUSAND characters a string is a perfectly efficient way to do it.